# How to enter metaplanes?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I search how rules works for metaplanes travel.

Core Rulebook p325

> Upon your first initiation, you learn how to travel to any of the metaplanes (The Metaplanes, p. 317), if you can use astral projection.

Street Grimoire p140

> Only characters who can astrally project can undertake a metaplanar quest unless they gains access to a spirit’s Astral Gateway power (p. 194). Before attempt- ing a quest, the character must prepare herself through a meditation ritual. This simple ritual requires a Force equal to the initiate grade the character wishes to attain. The ritual takes (Force) hours to complete. Successful com- pletion of this ritual means the character can transcend the physical world and face the Dweller on the Threshold (p. 317, SR5). The self-sustaining ritual protects the magician’s body with wards while the character is on the journey.

So, do I need a ritual (and spend Karma on the ritual skill) to go to the metaplanes as written in Street Grimoire, or can i go in as simply as an astral projection (with the exception of the Dweller of the Threshold)?

And about the Dweller, does it have some rules to manage the encouter?

Comment: I think you should ask the question at the end about the Dweller separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two connected, but separate things. The rules in the Core book are about **traveling** to the metaplanes and specify what you need to do/have:

- be able to astrally project
- be initiated
- succeed at the challenge presented by the Dweller

The rules in Street Grimoire are about a metaplanar **quest**, an ordeal you can take to help offset the karma cost of an initiation. It is only available as part of initiation. Performing a ritual (as per Core 295) is indeed necessary, but there are many other ordeals listed for characters without that skill (also, you can initiate without an ordeal). If you still wish to use a quest as ordeal, no one said that you have to perform the ritual on your own. You only need a single rank in the skill (as it cannot be defaulted), but anyone with a Magic of 1 or higher can learn it (Core 142). If you can get the help of someone with proper training to act as leader, you only need to not roll a glitch (or negate it with Edge), but most likely you will be rolling at least 7 dice, so it is rare.

So taking a metaplanar *quest* necessitates to perform ritual magic, but metaplanar *travel* does not.